# Flickering issue on switching an image with other image in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have an entry for Password and an `ImageButton`.
On click of image Button, it should change to a different `ImageButton`.
For the first time when cursor is placed and keyboard appears, on selection of the image button, screen flickers.

I am using `IsVisible` property, setting the visibility to false and true when required, still it's flickering.
It's a popup page. Image size i downloaded using material icons and there i selected iOS and Android, for both, size is 24.

The idea is entry is of password, so by default `IsPassword` will be true. Once user selects the image, image should get changed and it should show me the password and again if i select the changed image, it should change to the previous one and hide the password.

.xaml

```
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Current Password"/>
                <Entry x:Name="CurrentPasswordEntryText" Placeholder="Current Password" IsPassword="True"/>
                <ImageButton x:Name="CurrentPasswordImage1" Source="baseline_visibility_off_black_24" IsVisible="true" Clicked="ImageButton1_Clicked"/>
                <ImageButton x:Name="CurrentPasswordImage2" Source="baseline_visibility_black_24" IsVisible="false" Clicked="ImageButton2_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

.cs file

```
  void ImageButton1_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPasswordEntryText.IsPassword = false;
        CurrentPasswordImage1.IsVisible = false;
        CurrentPasswordImage2.IsVisible = true;
    }

    void ImageButton2_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPasswordEntryText.IsPassword = true;
        CurrentPasswordImage1.IsVisible = true;
        CurrentPasswordImage2.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show a screenshot to show the issue ？

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT
https://paste.pics/9IFFW-   this is with keyboard
Once select the icon , after flickering it changes its position and looks like this second one
https://paste.pics/9IFGF

Comment: Try to use one imageButton with changing its source.Check the below codes.(There's no obvious flicker on my side，i test on android).

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT i did that previously, it was flickering, then i changed to this one. It's easily noticeable in iOS. Image Button should be selected in presence of keyboard

Comment: I test on ios,it's not a very obvious flicker.I show a gif below.

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT  are you using popup page?

Comment: I probably know why, when you use it in POP, when you click on it, it automatically closes the keyboard and automatically adjusts the pop position, so it makes you blink, right？You could try it in a normal page,see if it has the same effect.

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT after flickering its changing its position to a bit up and yes keyboard is dismissing.

Comment: So it's the pop shift that makes you feel like the screen is flickering,i think it's by design.

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT if its a normal page, it's not flickering. But i want a popup. Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `Rg.Plugins.Popup`,but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT since i am already using a popup page, it is there in my .xaml file
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [BatchBegin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.batchbegin?view=xamarin-forms) / [BatchCommit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.batchcommit?view=xamarin-forms) methods:

.xaml

```
  <StackLayout x:Name="CurrentPasswordLayout" Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label Text="Current Password"/>
                <Entry x:Name="CurrentPasswordEntryText" Placeholder="Current Password" IsPassword="True"/>
                <ImageButton x:Name="CurrentPasswordImage1" Source="baseline_visibility_off_black_24" IsVisible="true" Clicked="ImageButton1_Clicked"/>
                <ImageButton x:Name="CurrentPasswordImage2" Source="baseline_visibility_black_24" IsVisible="false" Clicked="ImageButton2_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

.cs

```
void ImageButton1_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentPasswordLayout.BatchBegin();
    try
    {
       CurrentPasswordEntryText.IsPassword = false;
       CurrentPasswordImage1.IsVisible = false;
       CurrentPasswordImage2.IsVisible = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        CurrentPasswordLayout.BatchCommit();
    }
}

void ImageButton2_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentPasswordLayout.BatchBegin();
    try
    {
       CurrentPasswordEntryText.IsPassword = true;
       CurrentPasswordImage1.IsVisible = true;
       CurrentPasswordImage2.IsVisible = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        CurrentPasswordLayout.BatchCommit();
    }
}
```

Comment: No it did not work, it is happening when the keyboard is present and then u r selecting the image button, easily noticeable in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I am new in Xamarin, so forgive me if I am wrong. Seems like when the Image Source (or ImageButton Source, I presume) is changing, the entire StackLayout area is refreshed, so it is flickering. Try to put only one Image (or ImageButton) in one StackLayout, so the flickering only occurs inside the StackLayout which is unnoticeable because it is changing the image.